# iPhone app in the background

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way to start sound or pop-up message from closed iPhone app. 
Simply like "receive SMS"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe so. Apple has stated that no third party apps can run in the background (even though some of their apps do this). This is why there was a big deal about "push notifications" last summer (that has since gone no where, unfortunately) - this would allow an app to be sent some data from a server, and then appropriately respond to it.

You might be able to accomplish this if you write an app for a jailbroken iPhone, but then only those users who have jailbroken their phone would be able to install and use your app.

Comment: Apple demo'd Push Notifications at the iPhone OS 3.0 keynote:
http://i.gizmodo.com/5171796/iphone-30-os-guide-everything-you-need-to-know

Comment: What a difference a year and a half makes.  This info is now obsolete.  I posted an updated answer for people who are finding this question now.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this has actually changed after the question was initially answered.

There are currently at least two ways for a closed application to play a sound or a popup.

1. An app can register for a Local Notification while it is running, that will be called at a future time even if the app is closed.  The notification will display a popup and optionaly play a sound or set a badge on an application's icon.  Implementing this is easy:

   ```
       id localNotif = [[NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification") alloc] init];
       if (!localNotif) {
           return;
       }

       [localNotif setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
       [localNotif setAlertBody:NSLocalizedString(@"Hello!",nil)];
       [localNotif setAlertAction:NSLocalizedString(@"Hello", nil)];
       [localNotif setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
       [localNotif setFireDate:[[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:(60*60)]];           
       [localNotif setFireDate:[[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:(24*60*60)]];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
       [localNotif release];
   ```
2. An app (with the user's permission) can register itself with a remote server (yours or a service provider) to receive push notifications delivered to it from you (via Apple's system).  Once received, the App will optionally display a popup, play a sound, and/or change the badge on an applications icon.  There is sample code in the Apple documentation for implementing the iPhone side of this, and also a few open source projects floating around for the server side.  You can bypass having to implement your own server side by using a service like Urban Airship.

Answer (score 1):

Andy is right but Apple promised to enable their push system for 3th parties as well. So, I think you could just wait till they release it... no idea when though.

Comment: Push was initially supposed to be available by September 2008.  Months later it's still not available and Apple's not talking about it.  It might still happen but I wouldn't make any plans which depend on it.