# iOS: How to check if screen is locked when app is in background

Tags: ios, localnotification

Is it possible to notify an app (inactive OR active but in background) when screen is locked / unlocked?

Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3617552/1011125

Comment: Why would you need this?  Apple doesn't seem to allow this kind of programming, except in a push model.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9314869

Comment: I don't want to keep the application active for a background thread. I just want it to get notified when the screen is locked or unlocked, like a local notification. If it has to stay active, then it is prohibited, I know.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888490/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the screen is locked, your app gets these delegate messages:

- `applicationWillResignActive:`
- `applicationDidEnterBackground:`

However, you cannot distinguish this situation from any other situation in which you might get those messages (e.g., the user clicked the Home button to suspend your app).